# Trying to write regex that matches [ID] = 'anynumber'

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to write a regex that matches the substring "[ID] = '#number'".

this is part of the string that I mean:

```
[Patient.ID] = 123 And [Zorgtraject] = 123 And [Activiteit] Is Null Or [ID] = '86777' Or [ID] = '86778' Or [ID] = '86779' Or [ID] = '86780' Or [ID] = '86781' Or [ID] = '86782' Or [ID] = '86783' Or [ID] = '86784' Or [ID] = '86785' Or [ID] = '86786' Or [ID] = '86787' Or [ID] = '86788' Or [ID] = '86789' Or [ID] = '86790' Or [ID] = '86791' Or [ID] = '86792' Or [ID] = '86793' Or [ID] = '86794' Or [ID] = '86795' Or [ID] = '86796' Or [ID] = '86797' Or [ID] = '86798' Or [ID] = '86799' Or [ID] = '86800' Or [ID] = '86801' Or [ID] = '86802' Or [ID] = '86803' Or [ID] = '86804' Or [ID] = '86805' Or [ID] = '86806' Or [ID] = '86807' Or [ID] = '86808' Or [ID] = '86809' Or [ID] = '86810' Or [ID] = '86811' Or [ID] = '86812' Or [ID] = '86813' Or [ID] = '86814' Or [ID] = '86815' Or [ID] = '86816' Or [ID] = '86817' Or [ID] = '86818' Or [ID] = '86819' Or [ID] = '86820' Or [ID] = '86821' Or [ID] = '86822' Or [ID] = '86823' Or [ID] = '86824' Or [ID] = '86825' Or [ID] = '86826' Or [ID] = '86827' Or [ID] = '86828' Or [ID] = '86829' Or [ID] = '86830' Or [ID] = '86831' Or [ID] = '86832' Or [ID] = '86833' Or [ID] = '86834' Or [ID] = '86835' Or [ID] = '86836' Or [ID] = '86837' Or [ID] = '86838' Or [ID] = '86839' Or [ID] = '86840' Or [ID] = '86841' Or [ID] = '86842' Or [ID] = '86843' Or [ID] = '86844' Or [ID] = '86845' Or [ID] = '86846' Or [ID] = '86847'
```

I've gotten this far: `[\[ID\] = '{\d+:\d+}']` but that matches really strangely like it also grabs the `[` and `ID]` from `Patient.ID`.

all I want is a regex that makes a substring like `[ID] = '86845'`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
\[ID]\s*=\s*'\d+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YcF80D/1)

**Details**

- `\[ID]` - `[ID]` substring
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `'` - a single quotation mark
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `'` - a single quotation mark

[Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5BID%5D%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*'%5Cd%2B'):

[image]

C#:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[ID]\s*=\s*'\d+'")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToList();
```

To only get the numbers use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[ID]\s*=\s*'(\d+)'")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
        .ToList();
```